# reactjs - redux: how to access dispatch from selectors

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a situation like below:

```
state = {
     items: [.....list of items]
     filteredcount: count of filtered items done by selector
}
```

I have a component with the following code to pass state properties.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state,ownProps) => {
    return {
        items: getItems(state.items,ownProps.condition),
        filteredcount: state.filteredcount
    }
```

Inside the getItems selector i want to dispatch an action to update the filteredcount.

```
const getItems = (results,condition){
    filteredresults = ...filter results here based on condition
    dispatch(updatenumber(filteredresults.length))
    return filteredresults
}
```

where updatenumber is an action creator to update the state.filteredcount

How to do this

Comment: Why should filter be an action, shouldn't the selector handle that, also specifying an action in selector would mean that it is being fired everytime the component is re-rendered

Comment: because i want to store the length of the filteredresults in the the store.filteredcount

Comment: You need not store the length, you can simple get it in the component from the filtered array, this is directly derivable

Comment: yes, i think that will the best way. But incase is there any if i have to use dispatch is it possible.

Comment: Not sure, according to me selectors are not meant to dispatch actions and I don't see uses of it too. If there is such a case, you would rather call and action creator and then a selector and not vice versa. Thats my though, maybe some else has some ideas

Comment: thank you for giving the flow and logic. I did it by passing directly from the selector